# Control .py with Flask and Buttons

Tags: python, button, flask

What is necessary to get a button on a webpage work with flask? 
I just want to turn a LED on.

the html looks like:

```
<tr>
  <td><h3>Computer</h3></td>
  <td><p><input type="submit" name="btnled" value="ON"></p></td>
  <td><p><input type="submit" name="btnled" value="OFF"></p></td>
</tr>
```

How can i catch the pressed button in python to turn the led on?
What do i need? WTForms?

Edit:

the .py looks like this:

```
from flask import request
@app.route("/switch_led", methods=['POST'])
def led_handler():
    if request.form['btnled'] == "ON":
        print("ON")
    elif request.form['btnled'] == "OFF":
        print("OFF")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for a forms framework for something so simple.

You need to wrap the buttons in a form element, with an action pointing at your handler URL:

```
<form action="/switch_led" method="POST">
  <p><input type="submit" name="btnled" value="ON"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" name="btnled" value="OFF"></p>
</form>
```

And in the handler class:

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/switch_led', methods=['POST'])
def led_handler():
    if request.form['btnled'] == "ON":
        # do ON action
    elif request.form['btnled'] == "OFF":
        # do OFF action
```

Comment: I only get this when i run the .py file and click on the button:

`192.168.178.65 - - [01/Apr/2014 14:18:58] "GET /?btnled=ON HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.178.65 - - [01/Apr/2014 14:18:58] "GET /home HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Comment: Then your template is wrong, as that is clearly a GET request and the template I show above has a POST, and it is requesting `/` rather than `/switch_led`.

Comment: you're right! i forgot to delete a old form. I  get POST now but there is a new problem. When i click on the button, i get the error page with the error `ValueError: View function did not return a response`. Is this because i only have a `print("ON")` in my if function?

Comment: Yes, your view always needs to return a response, even if it's just `return 'ON'`.

Comment: Is there no way to avoid this? When i insert the `return 'ON'`, it opens a new blank page just saying "ON" but i don't want to change the site because i can't see all of my buttons anymore. I tried to retrun the html with the buttons and it works, but i want to load the html a second time. Is there a way to return anything that really nothing happens on my webpage?

Comment: Only by submitting the form via Ajax.